# Google Maps simples com ionic 2

Tags: ionic, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

Fala pessoal, tudo bem?
Seguinte, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em ionic 2 que precisará do google maps.
Porém a utilização não é via geolocalização, trata-se apenas da apresentação do mapa com um endereço(ou long + lat) pré definido.

Encontrei muita coisa a respeito do google maps, mas todos consistem na utilização de plugins... Há Alguma forma de fazer o que eu preciso de forma simples?

Comment: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Tutorial-for-Windows Boa sorte, estou a disposição!

Answer (score 0):

Fez uma excelente escolha quanto ao Ionic 2.

Vamos falar um pouco sobre os plugins. Eles são elementos construídos com o foco em fazer a ligação entre seu JavaScript e o Java, que é a linguagem que os dispositivos conseguem entender. De forma bem simples ao usar um plugin nativo como o Google Maps plugin do Ionic 2 ou até mesmo o Original do Cordova, você irá ter total desempenho de um recurso nativo, pois ao rodar o aplicativo para Android .apk seu JS irá se comunicar com os recursos nativos do dispositivo e assim irá executar sem problema nenhum que fora solicitado. A outra solução é se você mesmo fizer algo em Java que comunique seu JS ao dispositivo, mas ainda assim será um Plugin, só que feito por você. A única coisa que não indico é usar no ionic/cordova o Google Maps para web, que também funciona, mas limita você e deixa a aplicação mais lenta. Espero ter ajudado e bons estudos com o Ionic 2, ele tem crescido muito no mercado brasileiro.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa de um plugin para fazer isto, veja este que é recomendado no site oficial do framework

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

A documentação é clara, consistente. Veja que há exemplos no segundo link fazendo oque você quer, exibir um ponto no google maps, mais ou menos assim:

```
map.addMarker({
  position: {lat: ..., lng: ...},
  title: "Hello Cordova Google Maps for iOS and Android",
  snippet: "This plugin is awesome!"
}, function(marker) { ... })
```